# $E(X)$ versus $E(X|Y)$

Tags: probability, notation, expectation

Why is $E(X)$ considered a constant but $E(X|Y)$ considered a random variable? Seems like confusing notation since I'd assume the latter is a fixed constant "the expected value of random variable $X$ given the value of random variable $Y$".

Comment: If $\Bbb E[X|Y=y]$ is a constant then $\Bbb E[X|Y]$ is a variable respect to $Y$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the notation is confusing: $E(X)$ is a constant, but $E(X\mid Y)$ is a random thing.

If you haven't gotten to advanced (measure-theoretic) probability yet, then $E(X\mid Y)$ is usually introduced by considering
$E(X\mid Y=y)$, the conditional expectation of $X$ given that $Y=y$. Now think of this as a function of $y$, i.e. it's a function $h(y)$ mapping the value $y$ to the value $E(X\mid Y=y)$.  You should then regard the random thing $E(X\mid Y)$ as $h(Y)$, the result of applying the function $h$ to the random variable $Y$. $E(X\mid Y)$ is then a random variable whose value depends only on the value of $Y$.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not familiar with the measure-theoretic approach to conditional expectation and would appreciate it if someone could correct my response here (or even better, post a dumbed-down explanation of how conditional expectation is defined). But I suppose one way you could look at this is by noticing that - for example, if $X$ and $Y$ are continuous - 
$$\mathbb{E}[X \mid Y = y] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xf_{X \mid Y}(x \mid y)\text{ d}x\text{.}$$
Integrating the above only integrates with respect to the values of $X$, and still leaves values of $Y$ hanging, from which we may take expectations - so we are still left with a random variable.

Comment: The notation $f(x|y)$ seems strange... I think the correct is something like $f_{X|Y}(x,y)$.

Comment: @Masacroso No, that's pretty normal, to separate the variables of the pdf from the variables being conditioned on by a $|$ instead of a comma.

Comment: But the RHS is $E(X\mid Y=y)$, not $E(X\mid Y)$.

Comment: @Did I do understand that. If you know a better way to explain this, do tell.

Comment: Say, $E(X\mid Y)=u(Y)$ almost surely, where $u$ denotes the function defined by $u(y)=$ your RHS.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit unnecessarily elaborate machinery, but if you want, you can view $E[X]$ as $E[X \mid \{ \emptyset,\Omega \}]$. Thus, $E[X]$ is measurable with respect to $\{ \emptyset,\Omega \}$. But the only such functions are constant (exercise). It is more convenient to view constant functions as just being literally equal to their value than to view them as constant functions.

By contrast, typically $E[X \mid Y]$ depends on the value of $Y$, so it is still random.

Comment: I'm a layman; what is $\{ \emptyset,\Omega \}$? Empty/null set of states/outcomes?

Comment: So is $E(X)$ _actually_ considered a random variable (but just happens to only be able to take on one value) or is it an actual _constant_?

Comment: @user6596353 The point of the last sentence of my first paragraph is that you can *define* things either way, but it doesn't really matter which way you chose.

Comment: @user6596353 The above is in terms of the measure-theoretic formulation of conditional expectation. Here conditional expectation is actually always relative to some sub-$\sigma$-algebra, and conditioning with respect to a random variable is defined using the $\sigma$-algebra generated by that variable. $\{ \emptyset,\Omega \}$ is the smallest of all $\sigma$-algebras: it only contains the whole space and the empty set.

Comment: (Cont.)  For a function $f$ to be $\{ \emptyset,\Omega \}$-measurable, you must have $f^{-1}(I)=\emptyset$ or $f^{-1}(I)=\Omega$ for any interval $I$. That is, either all points map into $I$ or no points map into $I$. So the only such functions are constants. Thus if you define $E[X]$ to be $E[X \mid \{ \emptyset,\Omega \}]$ (a clunky but workable definition) then it is a constant r.v. But thinking about it that way is a waste of mental energy.

Answer (score 0):

> I'd assume the latter is a fixed constant "the expected value of random variable $X$ given the value of random variable $Y$".

$\mathsf E(X\mid Y)$ is rather: "the expected value of random variable $X$ for *any* given value of random variable $Y$."   You don't know what value you might be given, so how can this be a fixed constant?†   The expectation thus must be a random variable determined by $Y$.   That is to say, a function of $Y$.

$\mathsf E(X)$ is simply the expectation of $X$; it is not contingent on any particular outcomes.   It can only be a constant value.

---

(† $\mathsf E(X\mid Y)$ can only be a constant-valued function when $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated .)